# NLP User specific Text Corpora python getting Runtime error in hackerrank though program giving correct output

Tags: python, nlp, runtime-error

```
    import nltk
    
    from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
    
    import nltk.data
    
    import os
    
    def createUserTextCorpora(filecontent1, filecontent2): 'user text corpora'
    
        with open(os.path.join('nltk_data/','content1.txt'),"w") as file1:
            file1.write(filecontent1) 'write the filecontent1 to content1.txt'
            file1.close()
        with open(os.path.join('nltk_data/','content2.txt'),"w") as file2:
            file2.write(filecontent2)  'write the filecontent2 to content2.txt'
            file2.close()
    
        text_corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader('nltk_data/','.*')  'converting the txt files to text corpus'
        no_of_words_corpus1 = len(text_corpus.words('content1.txt'))
        no_of_words_corpus2 = len(text_corpus.words('content2.txt'))
        no_of_unique_words_corpus1 = len(set(text_corpus.words('content1.txt')))
        no_of_unique_words_corpus2 = len(set(text_corpus.words('content2.txt')))
    
        print(no_of_words_corpus1)
        print(no_of_unique_words_corpus1)
        print(no_of_words_corpus2)
        print(no_of_unique_words_corpus2)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        
        filecontent1 = input()
        filecontent2 = input()
        createUserTextCorpora(filecontent1, filecontent2)
```

'**When we run this program it gives output as above but throws runtime error as compiler message in hackerrank console. my output and expected output matches for all the test cases but finally ended with all test cases were not passed.** '

' filecontent1 = The amber droplet hung from the branch, reaching fullness and ready to drop. It waited. While many of the other droplets were satisfied to form as big as they could and release, this droplet had other plans. It wanted to be part of history. It wanted to be remembered long after all the other droplets had dissolved into history. So it waited for the perfect specimen to fly by to trap and capture that it hoped would eventually be discovered hundreds of years in the future.'

'filecontent2 = Begin today!" That's all the note said. There was no indication from where it came or who may have written it. Had it been meant for someone else? Meghan looked around the room, but nobody made eye contact back. For a brief moment, she thought it might be a message for her to follow her dreams, but ultimately decided it was easier to ignore it as she crumpled it up and threw it away.'

' Output:

```
94

61

86

66
```

'
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU42z.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0p0Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `print` statements and add a `return` statement:

```
return text_corpus,no_of_words_corpus1,no_of_unique_words_corpus1,no_of_words_corpus2,no_of_unique_words_corpus2
```

Comment: thank you! it works when I add return text_corpus,no_of_words_corpus1,no_of_unique_words_corpus1,no_of_words_corpus2,no_of_unique_words_corpus2. I was tried return earlier with return(variable) which does the same issue.